# Selecting the second occurrence of a class with CSS?

Tags: css

Given the following (dynamic) markup, I need to match the second occurrence of the class orange, regardless of how many divs have the class apple.

```
<div>
  <div class="apple"></div>
  <div class="apple"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="apple"></div>
  <div class="apple"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div> <--
  <div class="apple"></div>
</div>
```

Can it be done with CSS? Thanks.

Comment: It's too bad `:nth-of-type` only works on an element and not a class :-(  http://tinker.io/df4d9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this with selectors level 3 to select those that aren't the first one :

```
.orange ~ .orange {
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ihigum/1/edit)

The best is to complete the style with a rule describing the other `.orange` elements :

```
.orange, .orange ~ .orange ~ .orange {
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ihigum/5/edit)

Comment: Well... Why those downvotes ? Did you look at the demonstration ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but before you edited your answer it was wrong. And technically, the "add another rule" could simply be `.orange ~ .orange ~ .orange { color: inherit; }`, you wouldn't need the first `.orange`

Comment: If you want a CSS only, cross browser solution, albeit ugly: this is it. +1 - however could be optimized slightly. still ugly even optimized.

Comment: Thanks. It does work, but I have 8 oranges in my markup, so that would be quite a bit a ugly css.

Comment: @user1919784 no, you can use my style even for 8 oranges. See [demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ihigum/7/edit).

Comment: I know, but it would be a lot of css, especially for a more complicated example. Not really practical. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: tempted to downvote as the color red is applied to the class named orange in the demonstration...

Comment: @aw04 orange is the fruit. What would you have said for the apple ? In any case CSS is here to separate the definition of the style from HTML, and it's a perfect demonstration of how the color isn't defined in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Select second instance of class in HTML like:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li class="classname">text</li>
<li>text</li>
...
<li>text</li>
<li class="classname">text</li>
<li>text</li>
</div>
```

Using this CSS (tested in Chrome).

```
div ul li.classname ~ .classname:not(.classname ~ .classname ~ .classname)
```

In this particular case :nth-child(2) or :nth-of-type(2) not works.